# How can I get the duration of Youtube video with python?

Tags: python, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I get the duration of Youtube video? I am trying with this...

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id='the0KZLEacs')

print 'Video title: %s' % entry.media.title.text
print 'Video duration: %s' % entry.media.duration.seconds
```

Console response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/LearningAnalytics/Dropbox/testing/youtube.py", line 8, in <module>
    entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id='the0KZLEacs')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 210, in GetYouTubeVideoEntry
    return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntryFromString)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1107, in Get
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 410, 'body': 'No longer available', 'reason': 'Gone'}
```

Comment: Did you try with some other video id?

Comment: A 410 error means something went bad on youtube's end, not yours

Comment: Yes , I tried with differents ids and not works

Comment: Any idea @BansalUtkarsh?

Comment: trying to replicate the bug on my machine

Comment: 410 shows up on v2 of youtube api which has been deprecated. The current one is v3, maybe the library isn't updated?

Comment: @BansalUtkarsh Yes but I think it have to work is on the youtube api web. Any idea with v3?

Comment: I'll look into it tonight and will let you know.

Comment: @BansalUtkarsh I solved with pafy package for python, but I still want to know how I can do it with V3 Youtube API for python.

Comment: We could probably use the api directly, or do you need it to work with gdata?

Comment: With gdata, but at this moment only I need the duration, in the future I will need more details. @BansalUtkarsh

Comment: ok, i'll try to use gdata

Comment: thanks @BansalUtkarsh

Comment: I got it @BansalUtkarsh!!!

Answer (score 11):

## Two ways to get a youtube video duration

***First way:***

---

With python and V3 youtube api this is the way for every videos. You need the API key, you can get it here: https://console.developers.google.com/

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import urllib

video_id="6_zn4WCeX0o"
api_key="Your API KEY replace it!"
searchUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+video_id+"&key="+api_key+"&part=contentDetails"
response = urllib.urlopen(searchUrl).read()
data = json.loads(response)
all_data=data['items']
contentDetails=all_data[0]['contentDetails']
duration=contentDetails['duration']
print duration
```

Console Response:

```
>>>PT6M22S
```

Corresponds to 6 minutes and 22 seconds.

***Second way:***

---

Another way but not works for all videos is with pafy external package:

```
import pafy

url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyMHZVT91Dw"
video = pafy.new(url)
print video.length
```

I installed pafy from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pafy/0.3.42

Comment: If needed, you can parse the ISO duration using 
`duration = isodate.parse_duration(duration)` and then `video_dur = duration.total_seconds()` with the [isodate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate) package.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very usefull library called pytube, where you can get a good amount of data from youtube, as the channel's name, video's length, you can also download the video or get codecs, etc. heres the DOC https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html

```
from pytube import YouTube 

video = "youtube_url" 
yt = YouTube(video)  ## this creates a YOUTUBE OBJECT
video_length = yt.length   ## this will return the length of the video in sec as an int
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following

```
search_url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video_id}&key={YT_KEY}&part=contentDetails'
req = urllib.request.Request(search_url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(response)
all_data = data['items']
duration = all_data[0]['contentDetails']['duration']

minutes = int(duration[2:].split('M')[0])
seconds = int(duration[-3:-1])
```

This will decode the response using utf-8 encoding.
This allowed me to store it into a json variable.