# how to incease sleep time of selenium until song complete

Tags: python, selenium

how can I increase this sleep time to until my song finished. I am working on a voice assistance.

```
def play(self,query):
            self.query=query
            self.driver.get(url="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query)
            video=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]/yt-formatted-string')
            video.click()
            time.sleep(50)
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to set sleep duration to duration of the video which you can retrieve using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708632/1264304)

Answer (score 0):

When the single YouTube video is finished `Play Next` and `Cancel` buttons appearing.
So you can use expected conditions to wait until that element is appearing. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20000)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ytp-autonav-endscreen-upnext-button ytp-autonav-endscreen-upnext-play-button']")))
```